# introspection on custom typescript type

Tags: typescript

I define a custom type in typescript

```
type MyType = 'left' | 'right';
```

How can I check a variable match with this type?
How can I iterate on the possible values of this type? (to create a corresponding select element for example)

Comment: You can't do anything with your types at runtime. Which means that you can't check or iterate types in runtime.

Answer (score 6):

Adding type information at runtime is a stated [non-goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) of TypeScript.  That means they don't want to allow you to define a type and then examine it at runtime.

However, the reverse is just fine: create an object that exists at runtime, and use TypeScript to infer type information about it.  Here's one way to do it in your case.

First, add the following helper function:

```
function stringLiteralArray<T extends string>(...args: T[]): T[] {
  return args;
}
```

This helps TypeScript infer an array of string literals instead of just `string[]`.

Now you can make a runtime object called `myType`, and derive `MyType` from it:

```
const myType = stringLiteralArray('left', 'right'); // ('left'|'right')[]
type MyType = (typeof myType)[number]; // 'left' | 'right'
```

Then you have both runtime and compile-time type info.  You can check if a variable is of that type with the following user-defined type guard:

```
function isMyType(x: any): x is MyType {
  return myType.includes(x); // needs es2016 at least, or implement yourself
}
```

You can iterate `myType` at runtime, and you can do [exhaustiveness checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#exhaustiveness-checking) on `MyType` at compile-time:

```
function foo(x: MyType): string { // error, not exhaustive
  switch (x) {
    case 'left': return 'L';
    case 'rihgt': return 'R'; // error, 'rihgt' isn't 'left'|'right'
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that with a "simple type", but since [Typescript 2.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html) you can use enums with string values:

```
enum MyType {
    LEFT='left',
    RIGHT='right'
}

for (let i in MyType) {
    console.log(MyType[i]); //will print "left" and "right"
}
```

It works because during runtime an object named MyType exists and its value is `{RIGHT:'right',LEFT:'left'}`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

You have to write and use something like this:

```
type MyType = 'left' | 'right';
const MyTypeMeta = ["left", "right"];
```

There is [an old discussion here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628) on this subject, with a lot of linked issues. Maybe a hope with [this message](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628#issuecomment-298236279) but nothing complete for now.

Comment: it's actually the solution we try to avoid :)

Comment: @YoannAugen I understand, I had the same issue. I use this solution because I found nothing better (last January). But take a look to the last link I posted. It is really what we need. Maybe not perfect, but very promising.